# Deleted emails (that became corrupt and were repaired/deleted by scan.pst)

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

Can anyone help me... My outlook.pst file became corrupt and i had to use scan.pst to fix it, in the process some emails were lost, im not owrried about them, however some of them were flagged and now the flagging is still there, BUT the emails are not and I can not delete the flasgs and it becoming anoing... any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a repeat of the scanpst doesn't fix the problem, the easiest solution is probably to create new PST, copy everything into it, make it the default delivery location and delete the old one.

JR

Comment: Many thanks, I kinda realsied that may be the only way out, I did a half way measure which was to back it all up, deltete the pst and make a new one and then reinstate the old one and that fooled it into loosing the reference flags to the deletet emails. Thanks for your advice and help